# Lost my P4VP-MX motherboard support CD

Tags: motherboard

I have lost my P4VP-MX motherboard support CD and I have to use it to fix the problem on my PC:

```
bad bios checksum
```

Where can I download a copy of that motherboard support CD? I've browsed the ASUS website but the quest was a fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power down and remove AC cord from the PC, hold the power button in for 30 seconds, connect AC cord and see if the bios will post without error now.

If this does not work remove the AC cord, press and hold the power button for 30 seconds then use the cmos reset jumper to clear the cmos, move the jumper to the clear position for 30 seconds, then move it back to normal position, connect AC and see if the bios posts properly now.

[image]

.
You can recover by making and using a bootable floppy disc that has the bios file on it, all information to do [this is the user manual](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_478/P4VPMX/#download). This accomplishes the same thing as the CD.

.
[image]

Comment: by power down you mean turn off right?

Comment: Yes, turn off, shutdown, power down.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work :( It remains the same.

Comment: @user119915 Check edit to my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I had to hire someone knowledgeable to fix the problem, he removed the ram and it fixed the problem. I am very grateful of your effort trying to help me, thank you very mich!

Answer (score 0):

You can't download the cd, but you can download the [drivers and manuals](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_478/P4VPMX/#download) from the appropriate part of the asus site.

Unfortunately what you have sounds like a bad motherboard bios flashing, which would be a more involved to fix